# How to show last login / used details when user opens windows application or web application in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show the user his last used / login details using popup for few seconds when he opens the application.

Example:

When we open MS Word 2013, a small popup occurs showing last used details and automatically disappears.

OR

When we login to SBI account popup it shows the last transaction details for few seconds

The solution should be for any desktop application or web application.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**  if you are using database you try this method.

**Step1:** created Table

table name :LastUser
column 1 : ID
column 2 : Password

**Step 2:** Insert data

everytime user Logins into Apllication update your LastUser table with latest credentials.

**Step 3:** Fetch data

everytime user opens the `Application` on `Load event` of the `Form` you can retrieve the details from the `LastUser` table and display for few seconds.

**Step 4:** Create `InfoScreen` which will be displayed as initial screen for 5 seconds.

**Step 5:** Write your logic in InfoScreen Form_Load event to fetch and Display data from LastUser Table.

Try This:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*Fetch data from LastUser Table*/
        /*Display Data on Form*/

        // now set Timer to wait for 5 seconds
        timer1.Interval = 5000;//5 seconds
        timer1.Tick+=timer1_Tick;
        timer1.Start();
    }

   private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        Form2 mainform = new Form2();
        this.Hide();           
        mainform.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: thnkx man i have done